# How to add new line in xlsxwritter merge_range function in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsx, xlsxwriter

```
header2 = workbook.add_format({
    'bold':     True,
    'align':    'center',
    'border':   6,
    'valign':   'vcenter',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'font_name':'Calibri',
    'font_size': 12

})
worksheet.merge_range('B4:F6', "companyName:ABC\n Country:India", header2)
```

but the '\n' is not worked in this place. I applied Border for those merged area.

If i do this as separate line means i cannot apply overall border for this
ex:

```
 worksheet.merge_range('B4:F4', "companyName:ABC", header2)
 worksheet.merge_range('B5:F6', "Country:India", header1)
```

How do i apply border for overall area or how to apply new line?

company : ABC SQA 
 Country : India

[image: But now I got this]

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
'text_wrap':'true'
```

to the add_format using the first method you describe.

If this also does not work you can try using set_text_wrap() method:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#set_text_wrap

This will make sure text wraps at newline character '\n'

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
header2 = workbook.add_format({
    'bold':     True,
    'align':    'center',
    'border':   6,
    'valign':   'vcenter',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'font_name':'Calibri',
    'font_size': 12

})
worksheet.merge_range('B4:F6', "CompanyName:ABC \n Country:India", header2)


workbook.close()
```

It works just fine for me. Maybe you should try the latest XlsxWriter package.[image]